# Documenting private members with ASDoc

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, asdoc

Can ASDoc be set to document private members ala JavaDoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's pretty disappointing. But on the up side I did find what I needed in the -link-report option in the mxmlc compiler.

I was looking to make a visualization of the dependencies/class sizes/packages etc. The Flare site has a something like what I want , if anyone else is interested: http://flare.prefuse.org/apps/package_map

Comment: apparat.googlecode.com allows you to analyze classes and packages as well. It can also generate an UML diagram for you automatically.

It is open source and the inheritance graph / uml graph builder are pretty easy to understand if you are interested in your own visualizations.