# ASDocs Omitting Private Members

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, asdoc

Hail Stack!!

I'm developing a framework for my coworkers and I'm having trouble documenting it.
ASDocs as omitting the private members (even without @private directive).

Is there any way to force it to document it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the ASDocs documentation:

> By default, the ASDoc tool generates output for all public and protected elements in an ActionScript class, even if you omit the ASDoc comment. To make ASDoc ignore an element, insert an ASDoc comment that contains the @private tag anywhere in the comment. The ASDoc comment can contain additional text along with the @private tag, which is also excluded from the output.

It explicitly says "for all public and protected elements", which makes sense for API documentation: private members are not accessible from outside the class, and therefore remain hidden.

See this answer, too: [Documenting private members with ASDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881443/documenting-private-members-with-asdoc)

Comment: Thank you, weltraumpirat. I was hoping that it would be different, but I'll manage someway.